# How to derive this integral?

Tags: integration, approximation

I have relatively simple integral but I could not figure out how to solve. It is
$$
\int_{0}^{1}dz \frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)A^2}{B^2z+(1-z)^2A^2}
$$
$$B>>A$$
EDIT: You should use an approximation to you consider B>>A (B is much bigger than A).

Solution should seem like
$$
log(\frac{B^2}{A^2})-\frac{7}{6}
$$

Comment: @DroneScientist Why not?

Comment: (My previous comment was badly worded.)  What I do not like is that setting $B=0$ in the integral seems fine, the answer would be $\tfrac{1}{2}A^2$, but your answer gives $\log 0$ which is infinite.  This confuses me but perhaps I am not helping at all!

Comment: @DroneScientist I think you should not think B as zero.